# Question about Gronwall Lemma (positive hypothesis)

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

> Let $u, v : [a, b[ \rightarrow \Bbb R^+$ be two continuous functions
>   such that for $C \geq 0 $, we have $u(t) \leq C + \int_{a}^{t}u(s)v(s)
> > ds \ \forall t \in [a, b[$.
>
> Then $u(t) \leq C\exp \left( \int_{a}^{t}v(s) ds \right) \ \forall t \in [a, b[$.

I don't understand why we need that $u, v$ are positive functions. Suppose $C \gt 0$.

If we define $f(t) = C + \int_{a}^{t}u(s)v(s)ds$, $g(t) = C\exp\left( \int_{a}^{t}v(s) ds \right)$, we have $u(t) \leq f(t)$, $g(t) \gt 0$ and

$f'(t) = u(t)v(t) \leq f(t)v(t)$, $g'(t) = C v(t) \exp\left( \int_{a}^{t}v(s) ds \right) = v(t) g(t)$, therefore

$$\frac{d}{dt}\frac{f(t)}{g(t)} = \frac{f'(t)g(t) - g'(t)f(t)}{g^2(t)} \leq \frac{f(t)v(t)g(t) - v(t)g(t)f(t)}{g^2(t)} \leq 0,$$

i.e. $\frac{f(t)}{g(t)}$ is decreasing so $$\frac{u(t)}{g(t)} \leq \frac{f(t)}{g(t)} \leq \frac{f(a)}{g(a)} = 1 \Rightarrow u(t) \leq g(t) = C\exp \left( \int_{a}^{t}v(s) ds \right) \ \forall t \in [a, b[.$$

So why would we need $u, v$ positive ? Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: $f'(t)=u(t) v(t) \le f(t) v(t)$ holds only when $v \ge 0$.

Comment: You may not have $u(t)v(t)\leq f(t)v(t)$ if $v(t)$ is not assumed to be nonnegative. And there is no condition on the sign of $u(t)$ as you have verified.

Comment: An explicit counterexample is $u = 1, v = -1, C = 2$ on the interval $[0, 1]$.